# Why doesn't selenium click?(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

The other day, I started using the Selenium library to press buttons on YouTube, and everything was fine, but the other day, for some reason, it stopped pressing buttons, I didn’t change anything, everything was exactly the same, and when I checked the code on another computer, everything was fine, and most importantly, he didn’t even
gives me errors and pretends that everything went well!
What to do in this situation, I will be glad to every answer! (Worked in python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'url video'
FILE_NAME_PROFILE = "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + FILE_NAME_PROFILE)
driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
like = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-icon[@class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"]')
like.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you try inspecting the element on a web browser? Then confirm that class name has not changed

Comment: @Olamide226 Everything is fine, nothing has changed

Comment: add try-except and check what exception you are getting.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara She is not ther. The code ends with 'successful', although there were no actions

Comment: add 2-sec sleep after a click on like and check n browser what's going on.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Already added and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting as thus:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait ##new line of code

url = 'url video'
FILE_NAME_PROFILE = "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + FILE_NAME_PROFILE)
driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

inp_xpath_search = '//yt-icon[@class="style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer"]'

like = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath_search))

like.click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: She is not ther. The code ends with 'successful', although there were no actions